# `^ is giving \uparrow instead of \hat in AUCTeX with CDLaTeX

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

I am very new to Emacs using AUCTeX + the minor mode CDLaTeX to type math documents. According to what I read in [Auctex reference card](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall11/sta244/computing/auctex-refcard.pdf) the keybinding `` `^ `` should give me `\hat` but this is giving `\uparrow` instead, please help me to understand. Also please tell me how to get `\hat{.}` (`.` represents the cursor).

Comment: @Drew are you able to get my question now?

Comment: Try `C-h k ^`, to at least tell us what that key is bound to. You can also search the Auctex and cdlatex code for that command, to see where it might be bound to that key. Do you see the problem if you only use one of the two (Auctex and cdlatex)?

Comment: You should check the values of the variables `LaTeX-math-list` and `LaTeX-math-default`: in a LaTeX buffer issues the commands `C-h v LaTeX-math-list RET` and `C-h v LaTeX-math-default RET`. Paste the values of those variables in the question

Comment: By default auctex should give `\hat{.}` from that keybinding.  However, `cdlatex` changes a number of bindings and its way to enter such an accent is via `'^` _after_ the content you wish to put in the braces.  See the source file of `cdlatex` at https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex which documents this.

Comment: thank you all for the comments, it is working after cdlatex mode is turned off. @giordano I think I am not up to that level to understand your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrewSwann. Found that $A'^$ gives \hat{A}

Comment: @TijuCherianJohn, `C-h v LaTeX-math-list RET` means: press `H` while holding down `CTRL` key (`C` stands for `CTRL`, the hyphen between `C` and `h` means they are to be pressed together), then press `v` key, then type `LaTeX-math-list` in the minibuffer (here you can use auto-completion with `TAB`) and then press `RET`, that stands for `Enter`.  This is the standard Emacs jargon to indicate key shortcuts (or key bindings) `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

By default `auctex` should give `\hat{.}` from that keybinding. However, `cdlatex` changes a number of bindings and its way to enter such an accent is via `'^` *after* the content you wish to put in the braces, e.g.

```
a'^
```

gives `\hat{a}`.  Examples such as `ab'^` also work giving `\hat{ab}`.

See the source file of `cdlatex` at http://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex which documents this.

Comment: for eg:  $A'^$ gives \hat{A}